# Process for dlang static linking

Tags: compilation, d, static-linking

Using this file:

```
void main() {
  import std.net.curl;
  download("http://example.com", "index.htm");
}
```

I can compile with D:

```
dmd z.d
```

However this creates a shared build relying on external curl library. How can I
create static build?

Comment: Linking is done using GCC.  Use the `-c` flag to prevent `dmd` from calling the linker for you.  Then you can manually link your program using GCC which can also link statically.  For more see: https://dlang.org/dmd-linux.html#linking

Answer (score 3):

You need static curl library to link to first. DMD for Windows comes only with dynamic linked version of curl. The wiki has instructions how to build a static curl library on Windows: https://wiki.dlang.org/Curl_on_Windows.
For Linux you can check if your distribution provides a static version of curl. Otherwise you have to compile it yourself.

With a static curl library you can simply provide the path to the library on the command line, e.g.:

```
dmd z.d C:\path\to\static\curl\lib
```

or

```
dmd z.d /path/to/static/curl/lib
```

You should always use `dmd` for linking. If you need to provide additional flags to the linker, you can use the `-L` command line switch.